# Netrender addon missing

Tags: add-on

I am unable to find the netrender addon in Blender 2.79b on fully updated Ubuntu. My son is starting to work on more complex scenes and we have a couple systems laying around that can be dedicated to this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The answer for me was to download from blender.org instead of installing using apt.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone else has this problem you don't need to manually install blender.

Go to the standard app repository that's preinstalled and type blender into search and it will bring up 3 versions of Blender. Do not install by navigating to the blender file as this will not contain network render.

One's Blender t-paw and the other two just say Blender open up the download page for each one and you'll see that ones called Blender followed by a load of letters and numbers and one just says Blender.

You want the plain version of blender not the one followed by numbers and letters which is a third party build and am not sure why this is installed as the default blender.

Comment: That is rather annoying. Using apt in a terminal does not show the others, or at least I do not know how to make it as I normally use RHEL. But yes, there are three options when using the Ubuntu store.